# MySQL - Store date as a value with an ID?

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization, date, eav

I've got a database with the following structure:

```
Elements table
+------------+---------------+---------------+-----+
| element_id |    user_id    | element_data2 | ... |
+------------+---------------+---------------+-----+

Tag categories table
+-------------+---------------+
| category_id | category_text |
+-------------+---------------+

Tag values table
+----------+------------+
| value_id | value_text |
+----------+------------+

Tag-element relationship table
+----+------------+-----------------+--------------+
| id | element_id | tag_category_id | tag_value_id |
+----+------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

An element can have multiple tags associated with it, even multiple values on the same category.

What the app does is to let the user put new `tag_values` as unique elements (categories right now are not user-editable, but may be in a future). As they are not associated to the user, if two users write the same `value_text`, then the same ID is assigned to it.

So, to have a data sample, the `tag-element` table - the most important here - would look something like:

```
+----+------------+-----------------+--------------+
| id | element_id | tag_category_id | tag_value_id |
+----+------------+-----------------+--------------+
|  1 |          1 |               3 |            9 |
|  2 |          1 |               3 |            5 |
|  3 |          1 |               6 |           13 |
|  4 |          2 |               6 |            2 |
|  5 |          2 |               5 |           15 |
+----+------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

### The question

As such, there is a category called `game_date`, which stands for the date where the element (that is an event) is celebrated.

Should the `game_date` values be stored as the other values, so two equal values for a date have a unique ID, or its uniqueness makes its performance poor?

I mean, it can be possible for multiple events to be on the same date and hour, but I don't know if it would be better another kind of structure where that date is stored as a `Date` field on any of the tables above. *Just as the `game_date` can be also other categories involving date (such as `game_recorded`, etc.).*

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have reinvented "Entity-Attribute-Value" schema.  This will be painful in the long run.  Meanwhile...

Do not "normalize" dates or other 'continuous' values (such as `FLOAT`).

The `DATE` datatype is only 3 bytes, and may as well be put in whatever table it best fits in, not normalized into an attribute table.

Relationship tables *usually* do not need an `AUTO_INCREMENT id PRIMARY KEY` since a combination of columns makes a better PK.  More tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Comment: Thank you! I will wait to see if someone comes with another approach, but I will mark this as the answer by tomorrow! Thank you again!